# Regra SQL para filtrar apenas um mês em campo TIMESTAMP

Tags: sql

Olá.
Eu tenho uma movimentação de estoque no mês 1, mês 2, mês 3, mês 4, mês 5... como eu crio a regra para que apareça apenas as movimentações de estoque no mês 3? Lembrando que o campo é TIMESTAMP.

Answer (score 1):

Há diversas formas de se fazer.

#### Alguns exemplos:

Usando `BETWEEN` para puxar um intervalo:

```
SELECT *
FROM tabela
WHERE timestamp BETWEEN '01/03/2018 00:00:00' AND '31/03/2018 23:59:59'
```

Usando `MONTH` para filtrar apenas o mês:

```
SELECT *
FROM tabela
WHERE MONTH(timestamp) = 3
```

Usando `MONTH` e `YEAR` para filtrar mês e ano:

```
SELECT *
FROM tabela
WHERE MONTH(timestamp) = 3
AND YEAR(timestamp) IN (2017,2018)
```

---

Documentação muito boa e completa: [Date and Time Functions - MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: Olá. Ótimo!!! Creio que a primeira forma servirá. Valeu ae!!

Comment: @Wagner se a resposta resolveu, [marque como correta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta)